# Problem with finding mistake in program with using valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind, reverse

I have problem with my program. I use valgrind, but I can not find where is the problem. What can I change in the code. Here is the error in valgrind:

```
==14892== Invalid read of size 1
==14892==    at 0x4C32D44: __strlen_sse2 (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14892==    by 0x4EBC9D1: puts (ioputs.c:35)
==14892==    by 0x10878D: main (uloha2.c:10)
==14892==  Address 0x522d04c is 0 bytes after a block of size 12 alloc'd
==14892==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==14892==    by 0x1087D2: reverse (uloha2.c:19)
==14892==    by 0x10877D: main (uloha2.c:9)
==14892==
!DLROW OLLEH
==14892==
==14892== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14892==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14892==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,036 bytes allocated
==14892==
==14892== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==14892==
==14892== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14892== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

And here is part of my code, where the mistake can be.

```
int main(){
  char* reversed = reverse("Hello world!");
  printf("%s\n", reversed);
  free(reversed);
}

char* reverse(const char* text){
  if(text==NULL){
    return NULL;
  }

  char *novy=(char*)malloc(strlen(text));
  for(int j=0;j<strlen(text);j++){
    novy[j]=toupper(text[j]);
  }

 int p=strlen(text)-1;
 int size=strlen(text); 

 for(int i=0;i<(size/2);i++){
    char tmp=novy[i];
    novy[i]=novy[p];
    novy[p]=tmp;
    p--;
  }

  return novy;
}
```

Comment: `char *novy=(char*)malloc(strlen(text));` ==> `char *novy=malloc(strlen(text) + 1);`

Comment: ...which was suggested when you asked the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449405/problems-with-valgrind-in-language-c) earlier.

Answer (score 3):

You forget that in C all `char` strings are really called ***null-terminated*** byte strings. The *null-terminated* bit it important, and will be used to find the end of the strings (by e.g. `strlen`).

If it's missing strings functions will go out of bounds and you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The null-terminator is the character `'\0'`, and it's important to also remember that it's not counted itself by `strlen` and that it needs space in the string you create:

```
char *novy = malloc(strlen(text) + 1);  // +1 to make room for the terminator
```

Of course you also need to copy this terminator:

```
for(int j = 0; j <= strlen(text); j++) {
    novy[j] = toupper(text[j]);
}
```

Note the use of the *less-than* ***or equal*** operator in the loop condition. That will make sure that the terminator is copied as well.